# Can we findviewbyid() of an element not available in the main activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Can we get using `findviewbyid` an element not part of the main current activity but another hidden activity ?

Comment: no not possible i guess.

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able `findViewById` to find your `View` element it has to be part of the current view hierarchy. Otherwise you have to use an `inflater`. The inflater

> Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.

through the view object returned by the inflater you can call `findViewById`

Comment: something like you have a activity on button click you display a dialog. for the dialog you inflate a custom layout. then using the dialog object you can findViewById.+ 1 upvoted