# Unable to retrieve the EditText in a Custom Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I can't seem to wrap my head around custom dialogs.  I've tried many variations, but so far no luck.

This is my current xml for the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/edit_name"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center" 
              android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Word"
            android:text="Word?"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

    <EditText
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lookupWordEdit"
            android:inputType="text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code:

```
public class LookupWordDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private EditText mEditText;

    public LookupWordDialogFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    public interface LookupWordDialogListener {
        void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText);
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final EditText lookupWordEdit = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lookupWordEdit);

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_lookupword, null))
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Return input text to activity

                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                final EditText lookupWordEdit = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lookupWordEdit);

                LookupWordDialogListener activity = (LookupWordDialogListener) getActivity();
                activity.onFinishEditDialog(lookupWordEdit.getText().toString());
            }
        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        LookupWordDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

The code currently crashes with a null pointer exception on this line:

```
activity.onFinishEditDialog(lookupWordEdit.getText().toString());
```

I suspect that Im not correctly grabbing the lookupWordEdit.  The dialog is very simple.  How am I supposed to grab the entered text when the user taps the OK button?

Thank you!

Comment: use this inflater.findViewById(R.id.lookupWordEdit); to initialize edittext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
 View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_lookupword, null);
 builder.setView(view);
```

Now here you rare using EditText inside `AlertDialog`

```
EditText lookupWordEdit = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.lookupWordEdit);
```

Answer (score 0):

`lookupWordEdit` EditText is inside AlertDialog Layout instead of `DialogFragment` layout so you will need to use same View instance which you are passing in `setView` of `AlertDialog` for accessing EditText from AlertDialog layout do it as:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_lookupword, null);
// now pass dialogview to setView of Dialog
builder.setView(dialogview);
.....
```

now use `dialogview` for initializing  EditText from `dialog_lookupword` layout as:

```
EditText lookupWordEdit = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.lookupWordEdit);
```

Comment: in addition to the answer please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711427/can-we-findviewbyid-of-an-element-not-available-in-the-main-activity/16711474#16711474. You can find id of the current view hierarchy. In your case its a alert dialog. use the same to findviewbyid instead of getactivity()

Comment: I tried this just now, but it crashed upon creating the dialog.  But thank you, I think I must have done something wrong..